# How to create scales between min and max value using ranges in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I need to create a dynamic scales something like this

```
Range 1  = 0   to 100
Range 2  = 100 to 200
Range 3  = 200 to 300
Range 4  = 300 to 400
Range 5  = 400 to 500
Range 6  = 600 to 700
Range 7  = 700 to 800
Range 8  = 800 to 900
Range 9  = 900 to 1000
```

Here, ranges are 1 to 9 and minimum value is 0 and maximum value is 1000. These ranges, minimum and maximum values are dynamic.

So, I required a function to return the scales.

For example:-

```
    function getScales(minRage, maxRange, minValue, maxValue){
      var scales={};
       ..........
       ............
      return scales;
    }
   //Output:
   [
    {
        range   :1
        min     :0,
        max     :100
    },
    {
        range   :2
        min     :100,
        max     :200
    },
    {
        range   :3
        min     :200,
        max     :300
    },
    ....
    ....
    {
        range   :9,
        min     :900,
        max     :1000
    }
  ]
```

To get above result , I need to call the function like this `getScales(1, 9, 0, 1000)`.

[image]

This is what my actual requirement: if I call `getScales(1, 5, 4000, 418500)`;

Comment: "Please help me create a function" is not a good question. It should be more like "Please help me fix my function, I tried this and it is not working because [explain]"

Comment: If you don't know the answer... don't put such a comment like this. Now, you can copy the below answer if you want ... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
function getScales(minRange, maxRange, min, max){
    var scales = [],                  // Prepare some variables
    ranges = maxRange+1 - minRange,   // Amount of elements to be returned.
    range  = (max-min)/ranges;        // Difference between min and max
    for(var i = 0; i < ranges; i++){
        scales.push({
            range: i+minRange,        // Current range number
            min: min + range * i,
            max: min + range * (i+1)
        });
    }
    return scales;
}
```

You can call the function like this:

```
getScales(0, 9, 0, 1000);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "range": 0,
        "min": 0,
        "max": 100
    },
    {
        "range": 1,
        "min": 100,
        "max": 200
    },
    .......
    {
        "range": 8,
        "min": 800,
        "max": 900
    },
    {
        "range": 9,
        "min": 900,
        "max": 1000
    }
]
```

---

To get rid of the floating point errors in the output, you can replace:

```
min: range * i,
max: range * (i+1)
```

With:

```
min: (range * i).toFixed(2),
max: (range * (i+1)).toFixed(2)
```

Replace the `2` with the desired amount of digits behind the decimal point.

Comment: Could the person that downvoted me please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: cerbus,thanks for post a answer but please check this getScales(0, 4, 253, 467). Output: [{"range":0,"min":**0**,"max":42.8},{"range":1,"min":42.8,"max":85.6},{"range":2,"min":85.6,"max":128.39999999999998},{"range":3,"min":128.39999999999998,"max":171.2},{"range":4,"min":171.2,"max":**214**}] this is wrong.The first object should like this {"range":0,"min":**253**,"max":42.8} and final object should like this {"range":4,"min":171.2,"max":**467**}.

Comment: Hm, @Mohammedshafeek: That looks like some JavaScript float precision errors. (Basically, a flaw in the way JavaScript handles floats). What kind of precision do you require in your output? Only one digit behind the decimal point?

Comment: Consider adding the passed 'min' value as an offset to the output min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
var factory = function(start, end, minV, maxV){
    var result = [],
        st = (maxV - minV) / (end - start + 1),
        buffer = minV;
    for(var i = 0; i <= end - start; i++){
        buffer = st * i + minV;
        result.push({
            range: i,
            minValue: buffer.toFixed(2),
            maxValue: (buffer + st).toFixed(2)
        });
    }   
    return result;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(factory(0, 4, 253, 467)))
```

Some explanation: @start and @end describe number of ranges, @minV - first range starts with this value, @maxV - last range ends with this

Output

```
[{"range":0,"minValue":"253.00","maxValue":"295.80"},{"range":1,"minValue":"295.80","maxValue":"338.60"},{"range":2,"minValue":"338.60","maxValue":"381.40"},{"range":3,"minValue":"381.40","maxValue":"424.20"},{"range":4,"minValue":"424.20","maxValue":"467.00"}]
```

Play with [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y7eV/5/)

Comment: This doesn't work very well if the min range starts at something that isn't `0`, like: `factory(5, 9, 0, 1000)`

Comment: Of course i can start ranges with 0, but it not so important)

Comment: If the OP specifies a `min` __and__ a `max` range, you should assume __both__ are variable. `factory(5, 9, 0, 1000)` returns an array with this: `{"range":9,"minValue":1800,"maxValue":2000}` as it's last value. `minValue` and `maxValue` both exceed the value of the `maxV` parameter.
Sure, your code doesn't throw any errors, but that doesn't mean it __works as intended__.

Comment: @Cerbus i fixed this moment

Comment: I downvoted you because your code didn't work. The fix works, but there's no need to keep the old version around, now. That only leads to confusion. I'd appreciate it if you'd remove your downvote from my answer. (Unless there is actually something wrong with it.)

Comment: FUserThrowError,thanks for post a answer but please check this getScales(0, 4, 253, 467). Output: [{"range":0,"minValue":0,"maxValue":42.8},{"range":1,"minValue":42.8,"maxValue":85.6},{"range":2,"minValue":85.6,"maxValue":128.39999999999998},{"range":3,"minValue":128.39999999999998,"maxValue":171.2},{"range":4,"minValue":171.2,"maxValue":214}] this is wrong.The first object should like this {"range":0,"min":**253**,"max":42.8} and final object should like this {"range":4,"min":171.2,"max":**467**}.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(factory(0, 4, 253, 467)` Still returns `{"range":2,"minValue":338.6,"maxValue":381.40000000000003}`
You didn't recognize or fix the issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus i fixed now result is [{"range":0,"minValue":253,"maxValue":295.8},{"range":1,"minValue":295,"maxValue":337.8},{"range":2,"minValue":338,"maxValue":380.8},{"range":3,"minValue":381,"maxValue":423.8},{"range":4,"minValue":424,"maxValue":466.8}]

Comment: `Math.Floor` is not how you should handle this. `factory(0, 2, 253, 467)` now returns `maxValue: 466.3333333333333`. You're not just removing the float error, you're removing _anything_ that's behind the decimal point in your calculations.

Comment: Perfect!!!!Works fine.... This is what I required. Thanks a lot  FUserThrowError and Cerbrus.

Comment: @Cerbrus helps me very well )) Thanks Cerbrus

Comment: @Mohammedshafeek: I don't think it's fair you selected this as the answer. There were a lot of mistakes in his code, which were corrected only after I pointed them out. Heck, the last "fix" was copied straight from my answer.